# Class containing list of abstract superclass, do I need to #include all subclasses?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm making a boardgame. The boardgame has a class, `Board`, which contains a `QList<Tile*>`. `Tile` is an abstract class, which has a number of subclasses to indicate the different kinds of tiles, which have different functions. Now, since the constructor of `Board` needs to make all objects of these subclasses to put inside the `QList<Tile*>`, do I need to include every single subclass in `Board`?

And if so, I'm pretty sure it's bad practice, so would there be any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Why does the constructor of `Board` need to make the subclasses of `Tile`? Why can't the constructor of `Board` create an empty board and then add the `Tile`s afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to include every single subclass in Board?

If you try to use a subclass, you have to include it for sure. I do not think there is anything to circumvent here.

One thing you could do if this needs to be done in several places, i.e. not just in your constructor, then you could put the includes into a shared include. The several places would then include the shared include.

For instance it is unfortunately common that Qt end users include the whole module to avoid a few lines of include. IMHO, this is bad practice to allow.

Here is an example for your case.

#### main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"

int main()
{
    Test *test1 = new Foo();
    Test *test2 = new Bar();
    Test *test3 = new Baz();
    return 0;
}
```

#### test.h

```
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST
class Test
{
    public:
        virtual ~Test() {}
};
#endif
```

#### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
#include "test.h"
class Foo : public Test
{
};
#endif
```

#### bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR
#define BAR
#include "test.h"
class Bar : public Test
{
};
#endif
```

#### baz.h

```
#ifndef BAZ
#define BAZ
#include "test.h"
class Baz : public Test
{
};
#endif
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

TARGET = main
CONFIG -= qt
QT -= core gui
HEADERS += bar.h baz.h foo.h test.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Try to remove any of the includes or replace that with forward declaration in the `main.cpp` file, and you will see that it would not compile anymore.

Comment: Thanks for such a well-argumented response, and the extra information. I just wanted to make sure, I'm making this project for a Uni assignment, and they hold dearly to the GRASP-patterns. I was just worried that having that many association lines in my UML might raise some flags for them, with cohesion and coupling and all that.